# Merge api request using promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Due to the api of a plugin I'm using not working properly. I need to merge the two different requests. I am using the thunk below.

I can get a response but I cannot seem to check for `response.ok`, and return the combined data:

```
export function fetchCategories() {
    const firstPage =
        "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/categories?per_page=60&page=1";
    const secondPage =
        "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/categories?per_page=60&page=2";

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        Promise.all([fetch(firstPage), fetch(secondPage)])
            .then(response => {

                // check for ok here
                response.ForEach(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
                });
                dispatch(isLoading(false));
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
             // dispatch combined data here
            .then(data => dispatch(fetchSuccessCategories(data)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(hasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Something looks off, as the first `then` (correctly) expects an array of the resolved values.  This response is then passed on to the second `then`, which expects a value with a `json()` method.  Arrays don't have such a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the check for `.ok` fine because it's in a loop, but your `response` is actually an array of two Response objects, it does not have a `.json()` method. You could do `Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()))`, but I would recommend to write a helper function that does the complete promise chaining for one request and then call that twice:

```
function fetchPage(num) {
   const url = "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/categories?per_page=60&page="+num;
   return fetch(url).then(response => {
       if (!response.ok)
           throw new Error(response.statusText);
       return response.json();
   });
}

export function fetchCategories() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        Promise.all([fetchPage(1), fetchPage(2)]).then(data => {
            dispatch(isLoading(false));
            dispatch(fetchSuccessCategories(merge(data)));
        }, err => {
            dispatch(isLoading(false));
            dispatch(hasErrored(true));
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get `data undefined` when I dispatch `fetchSuccessCategories`

Comment: Are you sure you missed none of the `return`s in `fetchPage`? And declared `data` as a parameter of the callback? Notice I had used [`finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) (which is only recently supported in any browsers), not `then`, for settting `loading` to false. I edited to use `then` only now.